# Proving a theorem about the limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-writing

The theorem is as follows:

$$\exists L\in\mathbb R\ \bigg(\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L\bigg)\iff\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0\ \forall x_1,x_2\in B_{\delta}(c):|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\varepsilon$$

where $B_{\delta}$ is the set $\{x\in \mathscr D_f \ | \ 0<|x-c|<\delta\}$

It is quite easy to prove the implication $LHS\Rightarrow RHS$.

It is the other one I am struggling with( $LHS\Leftarrow RHS$ ).I'd appreciate a sketch of the proof or a hint on how to approach this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that *just* the definition of limit of a function?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, the difference is that it uses just the relationship between two "close" points to justify a limit exists.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that now, @David...and the claim is clearly false, of course, as $\;L\;$ isn't even involved in the right hand side of that $\;\iff\;$ implication...

Comment: @DonAntonio What I meant by the LHS is that the limit exists. Maybe I should then rephrase it as $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) \; exists$?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I guess the right hand side implies limit exists

Comment: Indeed so, @David...then the condition on the RHS is basically Cauchy's Condition.

Comment: @DonAntonio we were presented that it's called Dirichlet's criterion or something like that, but it doesn't really matter, in fact it's the same thing for functions as is the cauchy sequence for sequences. The problem is I don't know how to approach the proof: $RHS \Leftarrow LHS$

Comment: @David The LHS should be $\exists L\in \mathbb R\left(\lim \limits_{x \to c}f(x)=L\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud I corrected the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right hand side is called Cauchy's criterion for (continuous) limits.

A hint for the proof is the following:
The right hand side implies that for every sequence $(x_i)$ converging to $c$ (with $x_i \neq c$ for all i), the sequence $f(x_i)$ is Cauchy and hence convergent.

By "mixing" two different sequences $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ you can show that the limit is independent of the sequence. Call it L and show that this implies that $f(x)$ converges to $L$ as $x \rightarrow c$.

Comment: so rather than working with two distinct points in the domain of $f$, i.e. $x_1$ and $x_2$, I should work with sequences?

Comment: Yes, because for these you already know the Cauchy-Criterion (I hope).

Comment: I do. Thanks for the answer. I think I got the proof.

Answer (score 1):

David, some ideas for you:

We assume $\;\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L\;$ (i.e., the limit exists and equals $\;L\;$), and *by definition* this means that

$$\forall\,\epsilon>0\;\;\exists\,\delta>0\;\;s.t.\;\;|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\frac\epsilon2$$

so if $\;x_1\,,\,x_2\;$ are two such values (i.e., $\;|x_i-c|<\delta\,,\,i=1,2\;$) , then we get

$$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|f(x_1)-L+L-f(x_2)|\le|f(x_1)-L|+|f(x_2)-L|<\frac\epsilon2+\frac\epsilon2=\epsilon$$

and we're done.

Comment: I got this part, it is the other implication I can't prove; thanks though.

Comment: Well @David, you clearly wrote you can't do the $\;RHS\Longleftarrow LHS\;$ implication: this means you can't do the left-to-right hand implication...

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry I meant the other way. I must've mixed up the letters. sorry again. I'll correct it right away.